# Generating HD Wallet Addresses in Java Using Bitcoinj

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bitcoinj, java

Is there some method that can be used to get the address, private and public key for any type of supported coin in a HD wallet? I can correctly generate these for Ethereum, which I verified on https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

```
String seedCode = "elevator dinosaur switch you armor vote black syrup fork onion nurse illegal trim rocket combine";

// BitcoinJ
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed(seedCode, null, "", 1409478661L);
DeterministicKeyChain chain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(seed).build();
List<ChildNumber> keyPath = HDPath.parsePath("M/44H/0H/0H/0/0");
DeterministicKey key = chain.getKeyByPath(keyPath, true);
BigInteger privKey = key.getPrivKey();

System.out.println("0x" + privKey.toString(16));
System.out.println("0x" + key.getPublicKeyAsHex());
System.out.println("0x" + Keys.getAddress(Sign.publicKeyFromPrivate(privKey)));
```

I'm not sure how to do the same for bitcoin or any other coin. Is there some other way to get the public key, private key, and address? I am currently using the bitcoinj and web3j libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method toAddress

```
System.out.println(key.toAddress(ScriptType.P2PKH, network));
```